# Space between navbar and content

Tags: html, css

I'm currently learning some css and html and decided to practice by making a very basic webpage. I was successfully able to make a transparent navbar, but now I want to add a header yet every time I try to add a header it overwrites my navbar. The following is my code, any help would be very appreciated!

EDIT: I want to add a header right after (below) the navbar!

```css
.navbar {
  margin: 0 !important;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0px;
}

.navbar ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div> 
  <h1> Content </h1> 
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you want to have the header? can you add it to the code?

Comment: `position: fixed` takes elements out of the document's flow. It will remain there regardless of scrolling. If you want it not to overlap in the topmost position, add `padding-top: 90px` to `body`. If you want the top bar to scroll with the document, remove `position:fixed` from it.

Comment: Please create an [mcve], with the focus on _complete_.  As-is, it's impossible to see what the problem is, so very challenging to help you in any concrete way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a div for the header with a float:left, Then changed position fixed to relative and added a float left to your navbar so the items would line up and would scroll together.

```css
.navbar {
  margin: 0 !important;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0px;
  float:left;
}

.navbar ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}
.header{
width:100%;
height:100px;
float:left;
background-color:green;


}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul class="special_ul">
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="header"></div>
```

Comment: I wanted it on the bottom but sure enough, this was basically what I was looking for thank you!

Comment: just place the header div in the html under the navbar div

Comment: @CarlosRomero I updated the answer for you.  Glad I could help.